# json from C# client to PHP server - empty content

Tags: c#, php, json, symfony

I'm sending a JSON message from a C# client to a PHP server.

The C# client code is as follows:

```
    private String baseUrl = null;
    private String clientId = null;

    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    private Task<string> Send(string method, Dictionary<string, string> metadata)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new
        RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
        (
           delegate { return true; }
        );

        String jsonRequest = "{\"method\":\"checkLicence\"}";

        StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CLIENT_ID", clientId);
        String clientSecret = encodeClientSecret(clientId);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CLIENT_SECRET", clientSecret);

        var result = client.PostAsync(baseUrl + "/api", content);
        HttpResponseMessage response = result.Result;
        return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

On the server-side, the PHP/Symfony endpoint is as follows:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api", name="api")
 */
public function api(Request $request) {

    $this->checkAuth();

    $params = array();
    $content = $request->getContent();
}
```

by PHP debugging, I find that the `$content` variable is `empty` when I receive this request.  Why does it not contain the JSON string?

EDIT: to shed a bit more light on this - using Wireshark I can observe it seems my PHP server accepts the original POST request, and responds with a 302 (moved) response, and then somehow the redirect (now GET) request arrives at my `/api` endpoint, and has no content (because it's a redirect?)

Comment: what are the properties of your `Request `?

Comment: sorry, could you be more specific?

Comment: is `Request ` in your PHP code is a user-defined class?

Comment: @JericCruz `Request` refers to the Symfony class `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`

Answer (score 1):

You have a small typo in your JSON string. Key-values should be separated by a colon, not by an equal sign. Should be:

```
String jsonRequest = "{\"method\": \"checkLicence\"}";
```

Comment: thanks, but not the reason for the `content` arriving empty

Answer (score 0):

this was happening because the PHP server was redirecting an HTTP request to HTTPS, and thus the POST was lost, and replaced with a GET request, which has no body.